# Array of node list only returns the first element

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, web-crawler

I am using PhantomJS to craw some data

```
var root = this;
var a = [];

page.open('https://www.thegioididong.com/dtdd/iphone-x-256gb', function (status) {
page.evaluateAsync(function () {
    console.log("click now")
    document.getElementsByClassName("viewparameterfull")[0].click()
}, 3000)

setTimeout(function (a, b) {
    root.a = page.evaluate(function (el, i) {
        console.log("get data now")
        var temp = document.getElementsByClassName('parameterfull')[0].childNodes
        for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
             console.log(temp[i].innerHTML)
        }
       //Output html of all childNodes as intended

        return temp
    })}
    , 10000)
})

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("log now");

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        console.log(a[i].innerHTML)
    } 

       //Output only the first child of a, but a.length still shows 51 (enough number of child nodes)
    console.log(a)
}, 20000)
```

The first loop through the childNodes to console works - it prints every child onto the console

However the second loop doesn't seem to work - it prints only the first value and shows the error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a[i].innerHTML')`

What is the problem here?

Comment: Where does `a` come from? Is it the id of some element? It won't have a `.length`

Comment: Thanks for fast response, I edited the code to answer your question. `a` has a `.length` because it receives a `nodeList` from the `setTimeout function`

Comment: when I run `console.log(a.length)` it actually shows `51` - which is the correct number of child nodes

Comment: ?? How?  What code does that? `a` looks like it's a (relatively) global variable. *edit* oh I see the declaration now.

Comment: Yes, `a` is a global variable. I access it inside the context of below functions by using `root.a`. In the first `setTimeout` function, I assign `root.a` to a function which returns `document.getElementsByClassName('parameterfull')[0].childNodes` so that's why `a` (aka `root.a`) has an `a.length` of `51`

Comment: Note that in many browsers repeated output from `console.log()` is collapsed into a single line. Have you tried changing that `console.log()` in the loop to `console.log(i + " " + a[i].innerHtml);` ?

Comment: That's a nice thing you point out there. I just tried it. Unfortunately, it does not seem to be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PhantomJS docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html), the return value from `page.evaluate()` must be JSON-serializable. I would guess that PhantomJS's internal representations of DOM nodes are not.

What if you did this instead (inside the callback function for `page.evaluate()`)?

```
root.a = page.evaluate(function (el, i) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('parameterfull')[0];
  var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes);
  var temp = children.map(function(node) { return node.innerHTML });
  for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    console.log(temp[i])
  }
  return temp;
});
```

Comment: You are right about the return value of `page.evaluate` must be serializable. That might be the problem! However, your code does not run because `element.childNodes.map()` does not work. I actually tried to use `map`, `forEach` and other `Array` type function on `element` before but to no avail. I also tried `Array.from(element.childNodes).map()` and `element.childNodes.array.map()` but they wouldn't work either. Do you know how to convert them to array to avoid `for loop`?

Comment: Apologies for the hasty answer. This is vecause `element.childNodes` gives you a `NodeList` and not an array. An easy way to convert `NodeList` to array is with `Array.prototype.slice`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a champ. This is the second time you have answered one of my questions. The moment I saw you, I knew I was gonna get the answer, and get it fast! Thank you once again!